# Stacking images using Matplotlib.image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I need to stack two images with the same width to create a new image.

I currently have two images which are slices of the same image:

img is the name of the original image with shape (480, 640, 3)

```
    timestamp = img[:40, :200, :]
    variables = img[370:, :200, :]
```

I either want to stack these images somehow or slice the original image in such a way that I take the first 40 pixels and the last 90 pixels (as above)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
new_img = np.vstack([img[:40, :200, :], img[370:, :200, :]])
```